# html2canvas throwing non code breaking promise error in angular app.

Tags: angular, typescript, html2canvas

```
html2canvas(document.getElementById('imageArea'), {
  useCORS: true
 }).then(canvas => {
```

This line of code seems to be throwing this error

```
core.js:1440 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]
at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)
at resolvePromise (zone.js:775)
at eval (zone.js:858)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:4724)
at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
at Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
at ZoneTask.invokeTask (zone.js:500)
at ZoneTask.invoke (zone.js:485)
```

It doesn't break the code but stalls for a half second on there with that error. Has anyone else seen this issue when just trying to render an image from the canvas? I have had issues trying to fix it permanently. This is in an angular v5 project.

Comment: Make sure element by that `id` is actually present in the DOM when you invoke html2canvas.

Comment: Yup, it is in the canvas at that moment. It is larger than the screen size. Could that be an issue?

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? I have the same problem.